# How to map column names with EF 4.3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got problem with simple mapping (using EF 4.3.1 - code first approach)

```
public class Someclass
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And Table **someclass** with int **ID** and varchar **someclass_name**.
Now what I want to do is map **Name** with **someclass_name**

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Someclass>()
             .Property(r => r.Name).HasColumnName("someclass_name");
```

But id doesn't work and exception says: "context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."

I've also tried doing that by:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SomeclassMap());

public class SomeclassMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Someclass>
    {
        public SomeclassMap() {
          //  this.Property(r => r.Name).HasColumnName("someclass_name");
            Map(r =>
            {
                Property(m => m.Name).HasColumnName("restaurant_name");
            });
        }
    }
```

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong? THX

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use EF 4.3's migration utility. The error is notifying you that the model has changed since the database has been built and needs to be updated. Check out this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Thx. I've seen this link before. I'll try to follow that solution but is it only way to resolve that problem? Is it possible to use OnModelCreating and modelBuilder ... somehow?

Comment: - BTW as I read migration tutorial  there is nothing about  mapping different names between object and db.It's mostly about adding new properties or droping

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll avoid the migration notification or not, but you could try adding [Column("someclass_name")] to your Name property.

See the section named [Map a Property to a Column with a Different Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28VS.103%29.aspx)

Comment: It didn't. I can use that but isnt it for Entity Framework 5.0 Beta ?

Comment: Question is why did they do such a bug? I can write the code and its correct but it doesnt work correctly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Code First, but it's just seeing your property change as an actual database change.  It doesn't 'see' it as just renaming the property but *not* actually renaming the database column.  I'm not familiar enough with how it works to 'fix' it such that it doesn't see this as an actual database change, just a property name change. :(

Comment: Hi, I got solution. We need to turn off context change checking by that Database.SetInitializer<SomeDB>(null); And than we can map column names.

Answer (score 0):

I installed EF 5 and had this same problems.
 what I "discovered" is that

> > [Column("Name")]
> >     public  string Name1 { get; set; }

means that **Name1** points to field "**Name**" in **DB**.  So I didnt change field name, I changed property name in my class and I let EF know that this "Name1" points to "Name".
It's  a bit strange approach but it works this way. DB probably writes down somewhere DB hash and checks if it change. But I don't know yet where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
Database.SetInitializer<SomeDB>(null);
```

We need to turn of **database context checking**.